# How do I print pages from a book I own on Google play?

Tags: printing, google-play-books

I own a book on Google Play that I just recently purchased. I can read it via Google Play on both my browser and my smartphone. However, I want to print the certain pages from the book as how they appear on Google Play's Chrome browser. Using a Ctrl+P command generates a window with the text, "Preview cannot be displayed", meaning I cannot select certain page numbers that I wish to print. I know that it's not my printer malfunctioning because I can print documents on other websites accessed through Chrome, such as news articles.

Is there any way to print via Google Play?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I wanted to print 4 pages from a book I bought on Google Play. The easiest way I found was to use the Snipping Tool that comes with Windows. Any sort of screen capture tool should work.

I selected the section of text I wanted, which was the whole page. And then I used the print dialog to print the captured image. There is no need to save the image first. You could get fancier and copy/paste the image into Word so that you make adjustments to the size and maybe fill a page, but I just printed. There was a lot of white space, but that didn't bother me.